# Fitting non-linear equation to data using base R package

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

let say I have below data

```
Data = structure(list(col1 = c(31, 66, 88, 123, 249, 362, 488, 610, 
730, 842), col2 = c(2101.58953918969, 2103.57391509821, 2100.3292541732, 
2101.64107993765, 2100.51743895393, 2100.16708521627, 2102.1992412748, 
2101.06516854423, 2101.87929065226, 2101.25318636023)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to fit a non-linear equation as below -

```
library(stats)
nls(col2 ~ x1 + x2 / (1 + exp(-x3 * (col1 - x4))), data = Data, start = list(x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0), algorithm = "plinear")
```

However with this I am getting below error -

```
Error in qr.qty(QR.rhs, .swts * ddot(attr(rhs, "gradient"), lin)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

Can you please help me to understand what went wrong in my approach?

I want to use only base package to fit this equation as I can not download any contributed package from internet in my system.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `nls(col2 ~ SSfpl(col2, A, B, m, s), data = Data)` will be a step in the right direction (`?SSfpl`, "self-starting four-parameter logistic").

Comment: I am getting this error: `Error in nls(y ~ cbind(1, 1/(1 + exp((xmid - x)/exp(lscal)))), data = xy,  : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562`

Comment: Also, what is the problem with my original code? Appreciate for any pointer

Comment: It seems strange that you have `col2` on both the left and right hand sides of your equation. Should one of those be `col1`?

Comment: @GregorThomas This is good catch. I changed it. But still get error `Error in qr.qty(QR.rhs, .swts * ddot(attr(rhs, "gradient"), lin)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)`

Comment: With `clo1` in the lhs the error I'm getting is `Error in qr.solve(QR.B, cc) : singular matrix 'a' in solve`. But I'm using `start = list(x1 = eps, x2 = eps, x3 = eps, x4 = eps)` with `eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5`. (And @BenBolker's code gives the same error.)

Comment: It might just be that your data is too far from the shape the model wants to do. The equation you're using is for an S-shaped curve, but plotting your data it looks more like an upside-down U. The singular gradient may essentially be saying that whatever parameters the model changes, the fit doesn't get noticeably better. You **might** be able to get better if you can give the algorithm a clue by setting some better start values -- that's what `SSfpl` is supposed to automate.

Comment: Eyeballing things a little bit, `start = list(x1 = 39, x2 = 800, x3 = 1, x4 = 1)` gets rid of the singular gradient error, but it still doesn't look like it converges.

Comment: I changed the data in my original post. This data is more S-shaped. But still failed to get result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `SSfpl` with your current data I can get an answer.

```r
n1 <- nls(col2 ~ SSfpl(col1, A, B, m, s), data=Data)

pframe <- data.frame(col1=seq(0,900,length=101))
pframe$col2 <- predict(n1, newdata=pframe)

library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(Data, aes(col1,col2)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth() +
  geom_line(data=pframe, colour="red")
```

[image: data, loess curve + CI, and fitted four-parameter logistic]

The parameterization is not quite the same as yours:

```
         A          B          m          s 
2001.56354 2002.06645  642.30178   20.76013
```

Based on `x1 + x2 / (1 + exp(-x3 * (col1 - x4)))`,

I believe `x4` = `m` (midpoint), `x3` = `s` (scale), `x1` = `A` (left asymptote), and `x2` = `B-A` (`B` is the right asymptote).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems:

1. When using plinear the right hand side should be a matrix such that the ith column of that matrix multiplies the ith parameter that enters linearly and those linear parameters should not have starting values.  The linear parameters will be reported as .lin1 and .lin2
2. Better starting values for the nonlinear parameters are needed.

```
nls(col2 ~ cbind(1, 1 / (1 + exp(-x3 * (col1 - x4)))), data = Data, 
  start = list(x3 = sd(Data$col1), x4 = mean(Data$col1)), algorithm = "plinear")
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: col2 ~ cbind(1, 1/(1 + exp(-x3 * (col1 - x4))))
   data: Data
       x3        x4     .lin1     .lin2 
 295.3813  358.9000 2101.5302   -0.2175 
 residual sum-of-squares: 9.145

Number of iterations to convergence: 0 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 0
```